# Inherit ExportXlsxWriter odoo main controller not working

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to inherit ExportXlsxWriter **init** method but my custom code **init** method not calling.
I want to add something in init. Anyone can help ?

```
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import ExportXlsxWriter


class CustomExportXlsxWriter(ExportXlsxWriter):

    def __init__(self, field_names, row_count=0):
        print('Local::::::::::::::::')
        super().__init__(field_names, row_count=0)
```

Comment: "but not able to do" means?

Comment: My custom code init method not call.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you are calling anything

Comment: I think you're mixing Odoo's business models inheritance mechanism with python inheritance. Odoo's controllers aren't business models, so you have to use monkey patching for this change (because you should never change Odoo's codebase itself).

Comment: @CZoellner Thanks for your help, Now i achieved this using this solution.

ExportXlsxWriter.__init__ = new_init

Comment: I hope it's working ;-)